# <Brag about> vs <Boast about>

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, word-difference

According to the dictionary definition the two words "**boast about someone / something**" and **brag about someone / something**" are so close in meaning that I cannot differentiate between them. Are they interchangeable? If not, what would you interpret or how do you use each one?

Please have a look on the explanations below:

**Brag**

> To speak too proudly about what you have done or what you own:

**Example:** She's always bragging about how much money she earns.

**Boast**

> To speak too proudly or happily about what you have done or what you own:

**Example:** Parents enjoy boasting about their children's achievements.

For instance, do the sentences below mean the same thing:

> 1. Her son has written four articles and published them in many popular scientific journals. She always **boasts about her son.**
> 2. Her son has written four articles and published them in many popular scientific journals. She always **brags about her son.**

Or

> 3. He is a very wealthy man. He always **boasts about the money he earns.**
> 4. He is a very wealthy man. He always **brags about the money he earns.**

Please help me to find out any possible nuance.

Comment: I have no evidence to back this up (hence commenting) but I can't think of any examples where they wouldn't be interchangeable. If anything, I think to say someone brags its a little bit more negative towards [the subject], more derogatory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both words are equally old, yet **boast** seems to me *very slightly* better in a formal context than an informal one, and **brag** *very slightly* better in an informal than a formal one.

The only reason I can think of for this is that, when being scornful (in the school playground for example) it is easier to say, "He's bragging" with a sneer, than it is to say, "He's boasting" with one. You can drag **bragging** out to fit a good long sneer: "He's brr-AGG-ing". The first vowel sound in **Boasting** doesn't lend itself to sneering. So maybe as children we used and heard **brag** more than **boast**, and perhaps - from childhood on - we think of **boast** as more "teacherish": more formal.

However, do remember that this is a very slight nuance. In your examples the words really are interchangeable.

Comment: "Brag" has a slightly US feel.